# large number of strange samba log files not cleaned by logrotate

Tags: samba, logrotate

On my ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS I see a large number of log files with names like this:

```
log.2003_df_272d_9b00_810b_3c34_b13a_800c  
log.2003_df_272d_9b00_30b7_2646_c9ca_36c9
```

These are obviously created by XYplorer connections from my windows clients. They have size 0 and the number after `..df_` seems to change with every new connection.

I use logrotate to keep my logs clean, but the default config for samba does not handle the mentioned log files.

How can I get those log files handled properly?

Comment: Could you define "properly"? Would you like these zero-byte files deleted? Archived? Something else? 

Comment: Hello. This may not solve your problem but you are behind in updates. You show 20.04.2 and an up to date system is 20.04.4

Comment: With properly I mean a logrotate config for these files. I know I can write a cron job and delete files older than x days or anything like this, but this is merely a workaround. Better yet would be to set samba config to create log files which do not change with every session.